# Java2D: how place images around a center with the correct rotation

Tags: java, rotation, affinetransform

[image]

I'm having trouble placing images around a center with the correct angle of rotation. This is the code I'm currently using and the output can be seen in the screenshot. The number of slices can be dynamically changed by the user, so I need to calculate a new rotation value based on the number of slices, but I can't figure out the proper way to do so. I can arbitrary add a value to pictureAngle to adjust the rotation, but it will work only for this specific amount of slices.

NOTE: the first picture to be drawn is the one on the red slice on the right, which in the upper screenshot appears straight.

```
double angle = (double) 360 / this.slices.length;

for (int i = 0; i < this.slices.length; i++) {

    double pictureAngle = Math.toRadians(i * (360 / this.slices.length));

    px[i] = this.centerX + (wheelSize/2.1) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians((i * angle) + angle / 2));
    py[i] = this.centerY + (wheelSize/2.1) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians((i * angle) + angle / 2));

    p.addPoint((int)px[i], (int)py[i]);

    AffineTransform backup1 = g2d.getTransform();
    AffineTransform trans = new AffineTransform();

    trans.rotate(pictureAngle, (int)px[i], (int)py[i]);

    g2d.transform( trans );

    g2d.drawImage(pictures[i], (int)px[i] - (pictures[i].getWidth() / 2), (int)py[i], null);

    g2d.setTransform( backup1 );

    g2d.drawLine((int)this.centerX, (int)this.centerY, (int)px[i], (int)py[i]);


}
```

If I arbitrary add 103 degrees to the rotation it almost works, so I suppose I need a proper way to get this number correct based on the number of slices:

```
double pictureAngle = Math.toRadians(103 + i * (360 / this.slices.length));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
        double angle = (double) 360 / nOfSlices;
        double startingAngle = 90 - angle / 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < nOfSlices; i++) {

            // this is the old code

            //rc2D arc = new Arc2D.Double(0, 0, wheelSize, wheelSize,
            //        i * angle,
            //        angle,
            //        Arc2D.PIE);

            Arc2D arc = new Arc2D.Double(0, 0, wheelSize, wheelSize,
                    (i * angle) - startingAngle,
                    angle,
                    Arc2D.PIE);
```

The solution was to draw the first slice right in the middle (I highlighted it with a black slice - the picture is underneath) and put the first picture in it with 0 rotation and then progressively rotate the pictures according to the slice angle.

[image]